# merge identity matrices in specific way

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two identity matrices that I want to merge in a specific way. For example, if I have two matrices like:

```
[i 0]     [j 0]
[0 i] and [0 j]
```

I want to squish them together alternating between columns to get something like:

```
[i j 0 0]
[0 0 i j]
```

Anyway to do this with numpy? So with data like this:

```
size = 2
i = 1.2
j = 1.3
m1 = np.eye(size)*i
m2 = np.eye(size)*j

m1
>>>array([[ 1.2,  0. ],
         [ 0. ,  1.2]])

m2
>>>array([[ 1.3,  0. ],
         [ 0. ,  1.3]])
```

A function to return something like:

```
array([[ 1.2,  1.3,  0. ,  0. ],
      [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.2,  1.3]])
```

Comment: Please, add an example where the `0`s don't match (different values and expected outcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says - "`... squish them together alternating between columns`". So, with that target in mind, you could do -

```
np.concatenate((m1,m2)).T.reshape(-1,m1.shape[0]).T
```

or a shorter one -

```
np.dstack((m1,m2)).reshape(m1.shape[0],-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [273]: m1
Out[273]: 
array([[48, 31, 36, 30, 15],
       [27, 14, 14, 13, 30]])

In [274]: m2
Out[274]: 
array([[42, 39, 29, 35, 17],
       [31, 11, 39, 10, 28]])

In [275]: np.concatenate((m1,m2)).T.reshape(-1,m1.shape[0]).T
Out[275]: 
array([[48, 42, 31, 39, 36, 29, 30, 35, 15, 17],
       [27, 31, 14, 11, 14, 39, 13, 10, 30, 28]])

In [276]: np.dstack((m1,m2)).reshape(m1.shape[0],-1)
Out[276]: 
array([[48, 42, 31, 39, 36, 29, 30, 35, 15, 17],
       [27, 31, 14, 11, 14, 39, 13, 10, 30, 28]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another:

```
In [315]: out = np.zeros((size,2*size))

In [316]: out[:,0::2]=m1

In [317]: out[:,1::2]=m2

In [318]: out
Out[318]: 
array([[ 1.2,  1.3,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.2,  1.3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
np.hstack(map(np.transpose,map(np.vstack, zip(m1, m2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem

```
np.kron(np.eye(2),[m1[0,0],m2[0,0]])
```

is sufficient and you can add as many as you wish to the second argument

Comment: Elegant, but very slow.

Comment: @JohnMoeller You are kidding right? It is two by two.

Comment: Well, the _example_ is 2x2. If the OP really wanted to always operate on 2x2 matrices it would be easier just to construct the 2x4 matrix directly. It's usually good to assume that the OP wants to operate on something larger.

Comment: @JohnMoeller So you can beat kronecker product with slicing in terms of generality then?